# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')

Tags: javascript, eventos, function

Estoy iniciando con practicas en Js y me encuentro con el error detallado en el título al mmomento de probar el siguiente

```
const boton = document.querySelector('boton');

boton.addEventListener("click", function(){ alert("Hola!"); });
```

Comment: ¿Qué se supone que intentas seleccionar aquí `querySelector('boton')`? Agrega el HTML de tu botón.

Comment: Estaba intentando seleccionar un botón, pero lo que debí haber hecho es seleccionar el tipo de elemento ('button'), utilicé mal el querySelector. Gracias!

Comment: También quiero señalar que dependiendo de lo que quieras hacer debes escoger el tipo de selección más conveniente. Por ejemplo, si quieres alcanzar un botón en específico es mejor seleccionarlo por su `id` que es único, mientras que si quieres seleccionar varios elementos puedes usar la clase o el tipo de elemento y generalmente en ese caso se usa `querySelectorAll` para alcanzarlos todos y operar con ellos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revisa la documentación de [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), pues tu actual forma de seleccionar no tiene ningún sentido:

```
querySelector('boton')
```

`querySelector` usa [selectores CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors) para alcanzar los elementos.

Por ejemplo, para seleccionar por el id del elemento se usa `#`:

```js
const boton = document.querySelector('#boton');

boton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert("Hola!");
});
```

```html
<button id="boton">Click me</button>
```

Para seleccionar por la clase del elemento se usa `.nombreDeLaClase`:

```js
const boton = document.querySelector('.unaClase');

boton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert("Hola!");
});
```

```html
<button class="unaClase">Click me</button>
```

Para seleccionar por el tipo de elemento se usa `elTipo` (donde `elTipo` es el tipo del elemento, escrito en inglés, no en español, por ejemplo, para un botón, debes poner `button`):

```js
const boton = document.querySelector('button');

boton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert("Hola!");
});
```

```html
<button class="unaClase">Click me</button>
```

... Y así, hasta selecciones más complejas, combinadas, etc que se hacen por lo general con `querySelectorAll()`.